# Update contents of YUI3 scrollview

Tags: refresh, yui, scrollview

I'm using the YUI3 scrollview widget to create a horizontal slider to which I want to dynamically add new items and remove them as well. The scrollview initially looks like this:

```
<div id="scrollview-content-selected" class="yui3-scrollview-loading scroll-list">
    <ul class="checklist">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I dynamically add and remove LIs from and to the UL-element. However, as soon as the number of elements gets too large to fit inside the scrollview, I would expect the scrolling-functionality to kick in. However, the scrollview remains unscrollable.

The scrollview itself is created as shown below:

```
var scrollView_selected = new Y.ScrollView({
    id: "scrollview-selected",
    srcNode: '#scrollview-content-selected',
    height: 160,
    width: 200,
    flick: {
        minDistance:10,
        minVelocity:0.3,
        axis: "x"
    }
});

scrollView_selected.render();
```

Calling `render` obviously would not work, as this can only be done once. How can I get the scrollview to refresh itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find an answer to the question in the bugtracking system for YUI: http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2529372

Apparently there is a non-public method called `_uiDimensionsChange` which does the trick and nicely updates the scrollview's boundaries.